# I dont find codeigniter in my cpanel

Tags: web-applications, cpanel

I am new to webdevelopment.

I bought some web space from a hosting company.

I searched on the internet and found codeignitor for web application development

but I dont find it anywhere in my cpanel..

any suggestion

what I found was:

```
Software/Services

CloudFlare
CGI Center
Site Software
Perl Modules
PHP PEAR Packages
PHP Configuration
Optimize Website
Page Speed
Softaculous
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer my question:

In cpanel under software/services clicked on softaculous and searched for codeignitor and installed it..